# Override Attribute in Chef Recipe in a loop

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to create a recipe where I will iterate over a set of values and on each iteration I will override an attribute that is used to output a template.

So, for this code.....

```
count = 0

node['versions'].each do |a_version|
...
    node.override['jboss']['PORT_OFFSET'] = (PORT_OFFSET.to_i + count)

    template "#{JBOSS_DIRECTORY}standalone.xml" do
        source 'standalone.xml.erb'
    end

    count += 100
end
```

...after the run I would like to have each standalone.xml contain a port_offset that is 100 more than the previous version.

so they would look like this..

```
jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:8000}">
jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:8100}">
jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:8200}">
```

...etc

but currently they all are the same number.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

answering my own question:

I did this to get it to work. I passed in the variable to the template where the count was incremented on each iteration.

```
template "#{JBOSS_DIRECTORY}standalone.xml" do
        source 'standalone.xml.erb'
        variables(
            :port_offset => (node['jboss']['PORT_OFFSET'].to_i + count)
      )

    end
```

and in the template (standalone.xml.erb) I added this...

```
port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:<%= @port_offset %>}">
```